# Cannot get value from angular js with nodejs, jade and nodeclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, node.js, express

I m beginner for angular, nodejs and jade. I m not getting value from angular js with nodejs+jade on nodeclipse (eclipse IDE). I also notice on line 1 of /myProject/public/javascripts/myCtrl.js, eclipse is complaining 'angular is not define'. Followings are my codes.

/myProject/views/layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='/javascripts/lib/angular.min.js')
  body

    block content
```

/myProject/views/solutionTwo.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  div
    h1= title
    p Welcome here to #{title}

    div(ng-app="myapp1" ng-controller="myCtrl")
    {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}

script(src='/javascripts/myCtrl.js')
```

/myProject/public/javascripts/myCtrl.js

```
1. var app = angular.module("myapp1", []);
2. 
3. app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
4.    $scope.firstName = "John";
5.    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
6. });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chane your expressions to
{{firstName}} {{lastName}}

Comment: Hi EyeSpy, thank you for the quick response. I just changed it and it doesn't work. I tested above codes(without jade,nodejs,express and eclipse), just plan html, angularjs and normal text editor and it worked.